# Show the local storage doesn't work

Tags: jquery, local-storage

First of all my user types in a street where he lives

```
<label>Straat</label>
<input type="text" id="straat" class="form-control" required pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}">
```

i store it in a var:

```
$('#opslaan').click(function(){
    var street = document.getElementById('straat');
```

i do a try and catch:

```
try{
        localStorage.setItem("straat", street.value);
    }

    catch(f){
        if(f == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR){
            console.log("Error: Local Storage limit exceeds.");
        }else{
            console.log("Error: Saving to local storage.");
        }
    }
```

This works when i go to local storage i can see: straat = somestreetname

but when i want to load the localstorage later(on another page) it doesn't work

```
$(window).load(function(){
        eindstraat.value = localStorage.getItem("straat");
    });
```

Comment: No repro. Perhaps you are trying to send the data to a different domain?

Comment: Like how do you mean?

Comment: If you set the value on foo.com, you have to *read* it on foo.com too. Are you working in just one site?